# global url_for in JinJa template

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I read the base_template as

```
Example 3-10. templates/base.html: favicon definition
#+BEGIN_SRC html
{% block head %}
{{ super() }} <!-- preserve the original contents -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}"
    type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}"
    type="image/x-icon">
{% endblock %}
#+END_SRC
```

and the view function:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_moment import Moment

app = Flask(__name__)

bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
moment = Moment(app)
..
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',
                           current_time=datetime.utcnow())
```

As for the `url_for`, which was not get passed to context of `index`, how could employ it directly in the template.

Search JinJia2 docs thus did not find the `url_for` keywords, which actually import from the top level

```
In [1]: from flask import url_for        

In [2]:
```

Comment: Any context you're passing from view function can be available in `{{current_time}}` Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: but I did not pass `usr_for` to the context @RajaSimon

Comment: ty @RajaSimon could you please transmit the short comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Context Processor` acts as the bridge between HTML and Python and you can pass information from your view function to HTML.

**From Flask Docs**

*To inject new variables automatically into the context of a template, context processors exist in Flask. Context processors run before the template is rendered and have the ability to inject new values into the template context. A context processor is a function that returns a dictionary.*

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_user_last_name():
    return {last_name=user.last_name}
```

And now you can access the `last_name` in your template without passing last_name to every `render_template`.

Here is the list of default standard context variables for the reference.

1. config
2. request
3. session
4. g
5. url_for
6. get_flashed_messages